# How to create groups with address string from list of users with groups?

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm

I need to get a list of unique groups from a list of users, where each user has membership of one or more groups at different levels. The levels form a hierarchy that I want to be saved on the group as an address (kind of like an IP address). A user must belong to all groups in the hierarchy, so for example it's not possible to be member of a Level 3 group without also being member of all groups above. I get the list of users from an API that I'm not in control of, so unfortunately the incoming structure cannot be changed.

Given the following example list of users:

```
const users = [
  {
    'Level 1': 'first',
    'Level 2': 'second',
    'Level 3': 'third'
  },
  {
    'Level 1': 'first',
    'Level 2': 'second',
    'Level 3': 'another'
  }
]
```

When calling a function like: `const groups = getGroups(users})` it should return:

```
const expectedGroups = [
  {
    name: 'first',
    address: '1'
  },
  {
    name: 'second',
    address: '1.1'
  },
  {
    name: 'third',
    address: '1.1.1'
  },
  {
    name: 'another',
    address: '1.1.2'
  }
]
```

Comment: How come 'another' user has '1.1.2' address only being a member of level 3 group?

Comment: 'another' is a group name and it has parent group 'second' which has parent group 'first'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the values of the object in order, take an object as reference for seen names and build add a new object for a new name with all level informations.

```js
function getGroups(array) {
    var result = [],
        object,
        levels = { max: 0, value: '' },
        i, name, level, key;

    for (object of array) {
        i = 1;
        key = `Level ${i}`;
        level = levels;

        while (key in object) {
            name = object[key];
            if (!level[name]) {
                level[name] = { value: (level.value + (level.value && '.') || '') + ++level.max, max: 0 };
                result.push({ name, address: level[name].value });
            }
            level = level[name];
            key = `Level ${++i}`;
        }
    }
    return result;
}


var users = [{ 'Level 1': 'first', 'Level 2': 'second', 'Level 3': 'third' }, { 'Level 1': 'first', 'Level 2': 'second', 'Level 3': 'another' }],
    groups = getGroups(users);

console.log(groups);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```